# How to read synchronously data in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

```
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(value => {
      token = value
      console.log("Assigned token")
    });
```

What is the proper way to read this synchronously?
I tried using await/async, they weren't installed, and have tried several ways to install babel generators.

How do I install async/await in React Native and read synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install async/await. It's already there. To use, this is the way it should be. Declare the function as async then put await before AsyncStorage.

```
async Some(){
  var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      console.log("Assigned token:",token)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you are fine without await/async. You are just sending the "problem" of handling the promise to the parent function.

Usually, what I do, (if you are thinking about loading the auth token before continuing) is something like:

```
this.setState({loading: true}, () => {

     AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(value => {
      token = value
      console.log("Assigned token")

     this.setState({loading: false}, () => {
       this.continue();
    })

    });

})
```